# How can I look up username in view on cakephp?

Tags: cakephp

I use CakePHP 4.x and
I'm getting messages like: "Call to a member function read() on null", when I used //$user = $this->User->read(null, $this->Auth->user('id '));
//$this->set('user', $user); instructions on the default.php... :-(
Does anyone know about this?

I'm trying put the userna on the view default.php. I'm expecting some orientations about

Comment: Have you read the CakePHP 4 documentation and tutorials? It nicely explains how to implement authentication, how to get a username, etc. https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/tutorials-and-examples/cms/authentication.html

Comment: Yes but don't work...